# cannot removeClass("d-none") in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Can I removeClass("d-none") using javascript?

I have following code:

```
<div id="progressBar" class="progress d-none">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="min-width: 2em; width:0%">
      </div>
</div>
```

Using javascript I want to show the element so I used:

```
$("#progressBar").removeClass("d-none")
```

However this is not working. Should this work in Bootstrap 4? In bootstrap 3 I was using class "hidden" instead of class "d-none"

```
$("#progressBar").removeClass("hidden")
```

Was working fine.

Comment: How is this not working for you? JS removes the class just fine for me.

Comment: You probably have multiple `<div id="progressBar">`s defined on the page.  Try `$(".progress.d-none").removeClass("d-none");`  Either way, you have something else on your page.  Try creating an [mcve] - you'll see that `removeClass("d-none")` works fine *in isolation*.

Comment: "However this is not working." Any errors? Is it doing anything?

Comment: Also: "however this is not working" - it probably is working, but your `progress-bar` is `width:0` - so there's nothing to see...  try it without adding `d-none` when rendering the page.

Comment: Can you check in your console, which error you get?. I don't think, removeClass don't work for this case :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the replies.
I checked my code again and found out that the "removeClass" was nested inside an if else statement.
The problem was that in the new code it never got to the "else" therefore did not reach the "removeClass" command.